# autogeneration of config.xml and package.json

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I m a newbie 
i m try to suppress

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="git+https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git" />
```

from config.xml in order to resolve build problems with that plugin

every time i run

> ionic cordova build --release android

the line   appears again automatically in config.xml idem in package.json

where is the source(s) generating theses config.xml and package.json files and what is the process

thank a lot guys, i'stuck for hours with this problem because i can build properly

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have added this plugin to your project.
You will have to remove it:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

You can read the [docs about plugin/platform management](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/).

Comment: thks for that but there is a problem  cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: sorry for comment above !  

thks for your response but there is a problem:  <cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine> says no plugin installed <cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine> ends with error ... that why i want to suppress manually the reference to that plugin within config.xml and package.json in order to finish my built properly but these two are regenerated at each build